# most secure way to password protect admin files/folders?

Tags: php, apache, passwords, admin

what is the **most secure** way to password protect admin files/folders?

im on apache/php

Comment: Use google and read tutorials. There are many ways to do this.

http://www.apachesecurity.net/about/table-of-contents.html

Comment: @r3zn1k
I was afraid id get comments like this.
I Have used google with thousands of pages read about security, and i know of several methods of securing using sessions, or $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and .htaccess and all sorts of things, but none actually explain which is the best one to use, so i thought id ask this as a simple question on stackoverflow, see what this great, intelligent and up to date community has to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most secure way is to keep it off the internet alltogether ;-)

But irony aside, I'd suggest using .htaccess. Simple and requires no programming effort from you.

http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html#8

Comment: is $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'] equally secure or less secure than a direct .htaccess file?

Comment: Well, it is possible to do with PHP what Apache does, but there are circumstances in which it will not work, e.g. when PHP is run as CGI and not a module. See: http://www.phpro.org/manual/features.http-auth.html

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the `htaccess` method is to put the files that should be protected outside the web-root - somewhere where a typical HTTP request can't reach them - and have PHP relay them back to the client as needed.

This is useful in situations where you need more control over the process than Apache gives you. Like, say: if you wanted to integrate this with your PHP application's member functionality; allowing members that have already logged in access to the files while denying access to others.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess and .htpasswd with one of the 10000 .htaccess generators out there and use the htpasswd included in most distros to add users to the .htpasswd.

Answer (score 0):

**Securing admin folder with HTTP Authentication (.htpasswd & .htaccess)**

1. Navigate to http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html to generate
   username and password in an encrypted form

> Eg:
>
> ```
> username: User_name
> password: Mypassword
> ```
>
> Result will be depending upon your selected hashing algorithm
>
> Eg.:
>
> ```
> User_name:TX9D66ksKUR0o
> ```
>
> Save this in “.htpasswd”  file

1. Creating a “.htpasswd”  file on your web server other than the /public_html 
   directory. Preferably one directory above it in the /home folder which would 
   store the username and password in an encrypted form for the HTTP 
   authentication.
2. Add the following code to the .htaccess file inside the /admin
   folder on your server. Do not forget to put the correct path of the
   .htpasswd file in the following code snippet:

```
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Your_Name"
    AuthUserFile path-to/.htpasswd/file
    Require valid-user
    AuthName "Authorisation Required"
    require valid-user
    # IP
    # order deny,allow
    # deny from all
    # allow from xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```